# Java: Dataflow to bigquery sequential insertions

Tags: transactions, dataflow

I want to insert data into 2 Bigquery tables from a single dataflow job. where 2nd table insertion must be done only when data is successfully inserted to 1st table. Can anyone help how I can achieve/check whether data gets inserted and proceed to 2nd table insertion

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Wait signals](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html) this works in the next way

*Apply T to X after Y is ready*

```
X.apply(Wait.on(Y)).apply(T)
```

```java
PCollection<Void> firstWriteResults = data.apply(ParDo.of(...write to first database...));
data.apply(Wait.on(firstWriteResults))
.apply(ParDo.of(...write to second database...));
```

**Wait.on()** can be used with batch and streaming pipelines

Here is another useful [example](https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/post/apache-beam-initialization-destruction-task)